# How to find if a number if palindrome using recursion?

Tags: recursion, palindrome

I'm trying to check if a number is a palindrome. I have written the code to check if a string is a palindrome using recursion, but I'm having a hard time writing the one to check for numbers.

I'm passing just the number to the method, nothing else (eg, number of digits).

Anyone got any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your number to a string and pass the string to your already existing function you have written to test if a string is a palindrome.

You convert a number to a string using STR(NUMBER_HERE)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to do it with recursion?

Here's what I would do (in pseudocode):

1. Set var to middle digit place if size is odd, otherwise, half of size if even (e.g. 3 if the number has 5 digits, 2 if it's 4).
2. Loop:
   if odd, we skip the middle digit
   for (i = 0; i < digitsArray.size /2; i++){ 
       if (digitsArray[n-i]!=digitsArray[n+i])
           break;
3. Then if we popped out before the end, it failed.

Something like that.

Comment: Because I know I can do this without recursion. I'm new to concept of recursion and I'm trying to learn as much about it as possible.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was thinking of words, like madam, but I guess noon is a palindrome too.